# OpenGL / C++ - How do you fill an area surrounding a point on a mouse click?

Tags: c++, opengl

I've got the mouseclick handler correctly set up.  I have a drawing with some shapes.  Is there any way for me to fill the surrounding part of a point until it hits a polygon boundary.  Something like Microsoft Paint's "fill" command.

Thanks!

Comment: How are your shapes defined? Triangles? Line segments? Are they filled polygons, or just drawn line segments with an empty interior? If they are filled, is it a constant color, a gradient or a texture?
A screenshot would be helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider using OpenGL selection capabilities with **glSelectBuffer**.
Refer to [this chapter](http://glprogramming.com/red/chapter13.html) of the red book for explanation.

Answer (score 2):

The advice to use glSelectBuffer is pretty good. Once you've read that chapter, however, look for the "Now that you know" chapter, and look for a section named "Object Selection Using the Back Buffer" -- it's a lot simpler, and usually entirely adequate.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is called a [Flood Fill](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill) and it's a per-pixel algorithm; which means you're going to want to look at either Frame buffer objects with shaders or use the (very slow) glDrawPixels.

Answer (score 0):

Using opengl? I seriously doubt that ... What you can do ist to detect the shape selected by the mouse click and draw this shape in a different color.